# Cmake don't find Freetype on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, converters, cmake-gui

I'm trying to use Cmake https://cmake.org/download/ to convert the source code of EmulationStation (https://github.com/Herdinger/EmulationStation) to VS, so I can make a translation, and later recompile it.

But Cmake (3.7.0) keeps showing me errors:

> CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES: Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo
>   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: C:/Program Files (x86)/emulationstation
>   FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_freetype2:
>   FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_freetype2-NOTFOUND FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build:
>   FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build-NOTFOUND GLSystem: OpenGL ES

Any ideas (or even a tutorial about it) are very welcome, thank you.

Comment: So, do you have freetype installed? If so, where is it?

Comment: I was pre-compiled as described here https://github.com/Herdinger/EmulationStation, but Cmake is pointing another folder (Cmake/bin)

Comment: Solved. In Cmake, mark the checkbox "Advanced", then set all paths to respective dependencies. I saved all of them in another folder, set the paths and it's ok now (just another issue about a boost version, but that's another story).

Comment: What a poor question. It does not even include an actual error message.

Comment: What is poor about my first question? It was solved, Im not asking help about the second part commented above.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if someone thinks the question is "low quality". Anyway, more people can be facing the same issue, so I'll elaborate my own answer and show what I did to solve it (partially).

As explained on EmulationStation page, download all dependencies: SDL2, Boost, FreeImage, FreeType, Eigen3, and cURL. You have to compile Boost, FreeType, and cURL. A branch of ES, from Herdinger, says you have to compile FreeImage, too. The others, you can use precompiled libraries.

Organize your files anyway you need. I've put all of them inside a folder "dependencies" on the root folder of my project.

Open CMake, click "Browse Source..." and browse to the project folder (the ES folder, where the file CmakeLists.txt is). Click "Browse Build..." and find the output folder (create one).

Click "Configure" and select the compiler (I'm using VS2013). Cmake will show some errors, and here you start to point the proper files and folders.

[image]

Sadly, files and folders necessary for ES are a mess, too little information, so I still with errors (now related to Boost). But it's enough to answer this question, I guess. Feel free to correct me in anything if needed.