# CMake's find_package() can't find Freetype?

Tags: cmake, freetype, freetype2

I am looking for some guidance on adding Freetype to my game made in OpenGL. I am on Windows.

I have downloaded the most recent zip file from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/freetype2/) and I have unzipped it into my game folder. I would prefer to keep Freetype in the same place as the game, if possible.

I am using the CMake application to do everything, and I have tried setting the value of Freetype_DIR to almost every folder. I have tried downloading the [setup program](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm) through freetype-2.3.5-1-setup.exe, and setting Freetype_DIR to all of those too.

So in summary, now I have folders called freetype-2.13.0 and GNUWin32 in the game folder.

This is the error I cannot resolve:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY) (found version
  "2.13.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindFreetype.cmake:162 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:99 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

And this is the Freetype specific code in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Freetype libraries
find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJ_NAME} ${FREETYPE_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(${PROJ_NAME} PRIVATE ${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

This is an image of my CMake application:

[image: This is my CMake application with my attempt at linking the correct folder.]

I have tried doing include(FindFreetype) as well, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888274/linking-freetype-with-cmake), `find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)` seems to be preferred. I also used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064050/cmake-dont-find-freetype-on-windows-10) in order to try to solve my problem, but nothing has worked yet.

I apologize if this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937658/cmake-cant-find-freetype), but there is not really an answer for that one.

I also want to acknowledge that I may not be setting up Freetype properly, but I am not sure what "properly" would be.

I am using CMake 3.25.1

Comment: I have also tried to delete the CMake cache, to which the available values in the UI change to FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_freetype2 and FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build. I have also tried to set these to a myriad of folder options within freetype-2.13.0 and GNUWin32 without any success.

Comment: @user It turns out that no matter what I was setting those values to, the actual libraries values were not being set at all, and I had to manually do that by enabling Advanced. I tried setting them to the folders named bin, include, lib, builds, src, and subprojects when I was trying everything I could, but I realize now that it wasn't changing the library at all. I was trying to set the wrong values, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @user It was setting the previously hidden ```FREETYPE_LIBRARY_DEBUG``` & ```FREETYPE_LIBRARY_RELEASE``` to the libs/freetype.lib file. In my currently working solution, after deleting the cache, there is no ```Freetype_DIR```, for some reason.

Comment: I do not know how to make Freetype_DIR reappear, so I can't at the moment. I apologize as I am very new to using CMake and CMakelists.txt, and I found my current solution before I saw your comment! I will try your suggestion if I have any other troubles and I appreciate your help nonetheless!

Comment: "_I do not know how to make Freetype_DIR reappear,_" Add it again with the `+ Add Entry` button in `cmake-gui`, or use [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D) on commandline. But I'd suggest deleting the build folder to start afresh

Comment: I just realized that the first thing you downloaded was a source package and not a binary package. Did you [build the source package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project) and [install it](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project) before trying to use it? And can you provide a link to where you got freetype-2.3.5-1-setup.exe from?

Comment: I found it ([here](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm)) and I am using the files from that download in my solution! Sorry, should have included that originally.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I *may* have figured it out. I haven't actually started using Freetype in the game, but I have found a *potential* solution to this particular issue.

The correct folder to use is generated from [this](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm) setup file.

There are 2 names (FREETYPE_LIBRARY_DEBUG & FREETYPE_LIBRARY_RELEASE) under the "Advanced" hidden values. Setting those to the library file included in the GnuWin32/lib seems to have made everything work. I believe that the other two must be set to the /include folder, but I will update this answer if I learn anything else.

The values to set and what I have them set to are:

```
    FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_freetype2 -> .../freetype-2.13.0/include
    FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build -> .../freetype-2.13.0/include
    FREEYTPE_LIBRARY_RELEASE -> ...GnuWin32/lib/freetype.lib
    FREEYTPE_LIBRARY_DEBUG -> ...GnuWin32/lib/freetype.lib
```

If anyone can provide a better answer, I would love that, as I am not sure if this solution is the right one.